# Why .reduce() mutates my initial values only while it declares outside the function, but won't happen white declare inside?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, reduce, declaration

I am grouping every expenses into days by 7 days of the week.

First, I declare an array in `constant.ts` like this:

```
const weeklySchedule = [
  {
    label: "Monday",
    value: 0,
  },
  {
    label: "Tuesday",
    value: 0,
  },

  ...

  {
    label: "Sunday",
    value: 0,
  },
];
```

And create a function in `Expense.tsx`:

```
const getWeeklyExpenses = (expenses: Expense[]) => {

  const groupedExpenses = expenses.reduce((acc, expense) => {
    const day = dayNumberNames[expense.date.getDay()]; //return day of week
    const existing = acc.find((e) => e.label === day);

    existing.value += expense.amount;

    return acc;
  }, weeklySchedule);

  return groupedExpenses;
};
```

I found that the values in `weeklySchedule` keep accumulating everytime when I made some code changes, which I not expecting it is being mutating. But if I decalre `weeklySchedule` inside the function, the issue won't happen and it works fine.

Can anyone please tell me what is the different between declaring the variable inside and outside the function?

Comment: `acc` / `weeklySchedule` is an array. It's a reference type. If you create it once outside the function, you will mutate the same array over and over; the `const` applies to the variable (the reference to the array), not the array itself. You need to deepcopy / recreate the array in the function to get a fresh array. Note that the objects inside the array are again references, so they need to be copied too (deepcopy).

Comment: Because you are passing it to the `reduce` function as an initial object and modifying it inside the reduce body. Instead you can pass a clone of it like this : `[...weeklySchedule.map(r=> ({...r}))]`

Answer (score 1):

Your function **mutates** the value passed into it (`existing.value += expense.amount`).

If you create that array of objects once at the start of the program, then every time you call the function you are mutating the same objects in the same array.

If you create that array of objects inside the function, then every time you call the function you create a new one.